# StructureMap instance factory method

Tags: c#-4.0, structuremap, factory-method, open-generics

I'm trying to register a factory method for creating instances of an open generic type `MongoCollection<>`. However, when I `GetInstance` it appears that it is using a constructor of MongoCollection instead of the factory method.

```
var mongo = new MongoConfiguration("mongodb://localhost", "test");
For(typeof (MongoCollection<>)).Use(c =>
{
    var requestedType = c.BuildStack.Current.RequestedType; // set breakpoint here
    var type = requestedType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
    return mongo.GetCollection(type);
});
```

Then I do

```
ObjectFactory.GetInstance<MongoCollection<User>>();
```

When I run the `GetInstance` line it never hits the breakpoint inside the factory method, but it throws a `StructureMapException` saying "No default instance defined for PluginFamily MongoDb.Driver.MongoServerSettings". There is a constructor for `MongoCollection` that takes a `MongoServerSettings`, but I don't want structure map to use that constructor, I want it to use my factory method.

Any ideas why it isn't using the factory method? Is this a bug?

Comment: Did you try For(typeof (MongoCollection<User>)).Use(...); ?

Comment: @Rookian looks like it happens for that also. Guess it's not just for open generics...

Comment: hmm I tried it with a simple list of strings when I specifiy the generic element it works else it doesnt.

Comment: Either way, it's useless if I have to specify a generic argument

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I forked the repository to browse the code and realized its definitely a bug. I fixed the bug and sent [a pull request](https://github.com/structuremap/structuremap/pull/34), hopefully it will be merged and released soon.

Comment: deserves a +1 for getting into the source and fixing the problem yourself.